# Copy multiple target files from shortcuts in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management, copy-paste

Is there a way to select and copy a bunch of target files located in different folders by selecting their shortcuts from one folder in windows 7?

Comment: Yes, lots. You could program it using a programming language (such as .Net for a single example)...